# Wordpress: Get links to all posts on one page

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to add to my blog a page that contains links to all the posts in the blog. Not only 10 in a page or something, but all of them (if that's a bad idea I'd be interested to know why).

Besides links, the name of each post and its date would be nice as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should do it;

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'post_date' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
    <div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
              <br />  
            <?php the_date(); ?>
            <br />  
          <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note that the default 'orderby' parameter for get_posts() is actually 'post_date'. I've just added it in for clarity. Have a look here for how to configure [the_date()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date).

I agree, with the comment above about pagination. If you have a lot of posts, it might become unwieldy.

Comment: Note for newbie like me : If you want all the posts in a separate page that is outside WP structure, then don't forget to include `include 'wp-load.php';` on top of the page

Comment: I realise things have changed in eight years. I tried this using the PHP Everywhere plugin in WP 5.6 and get the most recent post details repeated for every post in my blog.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but I find the [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function to be the easiest.

This would indeed be a bad idea if you have a lot of posts, and since in most cases you don't know how many you might eventually have, I would at least provide some sort of [pagination](http://blog.ashfame.com/2011/04/pagination-approach-get-posts-wordpress/).