# wordpress page with all the post links shown

Tags: php, wordpress

I want a page in my wordpress with all the links of all the posts. Same question as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953585/wordpress-get-links-to-all-posts-on-one-page`

So in that post answer the following code is shown. I am using wordpress and testing it on my local server. So how to run this code and add a page in my site will all posts links.

I am not getting where to put this code.

```
  <?php
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'post_date' );
  $postslist = get_posts( $args );
  foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
      <div>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <br />  
          <?php the_date(); ?>
          <br />  
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Create a page template, place above code into it, and create a page that uses the template

Comment: You mean in dashboard there is pages menu and in that add new page and paste the code in that

Comment: Nope, i mean create a page template with your favourite php editor, upload it to your host, THEN go to pages menu, create a page, and select your new page template.

Comment: Alternately post this on a freelancer site.

Comment: I am using a local server. SO you mean save this code as templatelinks.php (but in which folder i have to place this code). And then go to dashbaord and pages and select this temples.

Comment: "wp custom page template" are the keywords

Comment: See above comment, combine with google. This is really too broad for stackoverflow.